# How to resolve data in session storage and return it or retrieve from API if null

Tags: angular

I'm making a web app using Angular 4. I have a route that needs to load data before the user sees the page. When the app loads a list of projects is displayed. I retrieve all information on this page already and when they click on the project I use a router link to navigate to the page, but I also use (click) to save the data in session storage. I am unsure of how to return the project data if its stored, or call the API if its not

project.html

```
<div class="btn-group-lg text-align:center; pr-3 pl-3" *ngFor="let project of projects?.data;">
  <button type="button" class="btnProject btn btn-outline-success btn-lg btn-block"
          [routerLink]="['/', 'projects', project.id, 'project-details']" (click)="onGotoProject(project)">{{project.address}}
  </button>
</div>
```

project.component.ts

```
onGotoProject(project: ProjectDataInterface) {
  this.projectService.setProjectData(project);
}
```

I'm getting an error in the resolve() function

```
Error:(24, 51) TS2345:Argument of type '(this: Observable<ProjectDataInterface[]>, observer: Subscriber<ProjectDataInterface[]>) => Proje...' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Observable<ProjectDataInterface[]>, subscriber: Subscriber<ProjectDataInterface[]>) => Tea...'.
  Type 'ProjectDataInterface' is not assignable to type 'TeardownLogic'.
    Type 'ProjectDataInterface' is not assignable to type 'AnonymousSubscription'.
      Property 'unsubscribe' is missing in type 'ProjectDataInterface'.
```

project.resolver.ts

```
resolve(): Observable<ProjectDataInterface[]> {
    this.getProjectData();
    return new Observable<ProjectDataInterface[]>((observer) =>
    {
      const projectID = this.projectData.id;
      const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

      if (this.projectData) {
        observer.complete();

        return this.projectData;
      } else {
        this.API.getProjectsInfo(projectID).subscribe((data => {
            data = this.projectData ;
      }
  });

  }

setProjectData(data: ProjectDataInterface) {
  this.projectData = data;
  this.session.store('project', this.projectData);
}

getProjectData() {
  this.projectData = this.session.retrieve('project');
  return this.projectData;
}
```

API.ts

```
getProject(id): Observable<ProjectDataInterface> {
    const URL = `${this.API}/project/${idd}`;
    return this.auth.refreshToken()
      .flatMap(() => this.authHttp.get(URL, this.headers))
      .map((response: Response) => response.json().data)
      .share()
      .catch(this.handleError);
}
```